# Moving from other contacts group in google contacts using google app scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I cant move my other contacts to my system group contacts via GAS

```js
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var group  = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Other Contacts');
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(group);
  var mainGroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");

  for (var i in contacts) {
    mainGroup.addContact(contacts[i]);
  }
```

I think issue in "other contact" system group name, but I can't find any information about names.

Comment: What is the output if you try to: `Logger.log(group)`. When you want to debug your code especially when you don't get any errors you should always look what is the value of each variable you are declaring. It is a common practice for every programming language, not just for javascript.

Comment: this code does not need to be rework. I wish know what a system groups have google contacts in google app scripts

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, 'Other Contacts' cannot be retrieved using ContactsApp.getContactGroup. They live their own life. To get those you need to use [People.OtherContacts.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts/list) method.

```
var people = People.OtherContacts.list({readMask:'emailAddresses'});
for(var i=0; i<=people.otherContacts.length; i++){
    var response = People.OtherContacts.copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup({
        "copyMask": "names,emailAddresses"
    },people.otherContacts[i].resourceName);
}
```